# css is auto checking my html checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I enclose my checkbox in a css class, it becomes automatically checked. How can I stop this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>website</title>
<style type="text/css">
.checkbox0 {
position:fixed;
margin-left:137px;
margin-top:119px;
font-family:Segoe UI;
font-size:9px;
font-weight:normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="checkbox0"><input type="checkbox" />s</input></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If we remove the `<div class="checkbox0">` and the `</div>`  we will see that it works normally however when it is with the css, it will auto check.

Comment: This shouldn't happen, and if I copy/paste your page the checkbox isn't checked. Perhaps you also include some Javascript file?

Comment: The problem is elsewhere. As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/fcvWW/, it isn't checked.

Comment: Your problem definitely is not the CSS nor the HTML you show here. You'll have to look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: hmmm, im using Opera. And I ran that exact example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sneaking feeling it's not your code but your browser cache. ;) Try deleting your browser cache and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be.Tried with this code but can't see it autochecked. problem is somewhere else. It might be due some other js file if included here or something else is conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not valid HTML:

`<input type="checkbox" />s</input>`

You have closed the `input` tag with `/>` and you then have a `</input>`. Please see if removing the `</input>` fixes the problem if you still see it.